# How to keep an html element fixed at the bottom of the window while resizing, but not at scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to do exactly as [this page](http://www.standardhotels.com/new-york/properties/east-village) does, If you resize the second page, you'll notice that the container header (the one with the phone numbers, address and "book now" button) keeps fixed at the bottom of the window, but if you start scrolling down the page, you can continue with the rest of the content. How can I do that?

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap 3.

Comment: Please post a **minimal working example** of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: I'm confused. It's not fixed to the bottom of the window if it moves if you start scrolling. It seems to act like a regular element to me, with the book now button being stuck to the bottom of the page. (as a seperate element) Am I missing somthing?

Comment: I don't think the element is stuck to the bottom of the screen, I think the area containing the image is shrinking to a certain % and therefore giving the impression  that the other element is stuck to the bottom. If you resize v. quickly using the mouse you'll see a lag while the image resizes (in Chrome, anyway). Haven't looked at the CSS in detail but that's my impression. I'm not aware of anyway to make an element stick to the bottom just while resizing, that's just not how css works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They use `calc(100vh - 75px)` to calculate the height of the top div.
So the first div will always cover the entire viewport height (100vh) minus 75px.

```
.property-page .full-screen {
    min-height: calc(100vh - 75px);
    height: calc(100vh - 75px);
}
```

The "book now" button is just an element with `position:fixed;`

Something like this should do what you want:

https://jsfiddle.net/zaw0mptm/2/

Comment: Is exactly what I wanted to do, so there wasn't any fixing at all, just resizing of the first div depending of the window height. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can check it

```
<body>
   <div id="footer"></div>
</body>
```

then use this css

```
#footer {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100px;   
  background:blue;//optional
 }
```